# Retrofit, Observable and the never-ending code

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

Given the simple interface:

```
public interface Api {
    @Get("/{id}")
    Observable<Person> getPerson(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

and a call like:

```
api.getPerson("me").toBlocking().single();
```

everything works as expected except my application doesn't terminate. It doesn't matter if I subscribe to the Observable and unsubscribe when complete rather than block, my code will not terminate.

To be clear, this is not an Android app.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go for the "it's late" defence.

I simply changed the call to subscribe on the io scheduler and observe on the immediate scheduler like so:

```
api.getPerson("me").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).toBlocking().single();
```

Simples.